# Any difference between `gcloud app deploy index.yaml` and `gcloud datastore indexes create`

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

To deploy index.yaml, what is the difference following two commands?

1. `gcloud app deploy index.yaml`
2. `gcloud datastore indexes create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The main reason for both existing is that Cloud Datastore used to be an App Engine specific service and so all index manipulation was done through that product. Now Datastore can be used as a more general purpose storage product and so how it's own command group in gcloud. Leaving it under `gcloud app deploy` is just a convenience to existing App Engine users.

Comment: I could understand what happened up until now.Thanks!